# Switch on when power is off

Tags: switches

I'm looking for unknown element U1, which fulfils the following requirements:

1. When power is ON, there shall be no connection between P1, P2, P3, and P4, i.e. replacing U1 with air would work. (Some nA leakage current would be OK.)
2. When power is OFF, electrons shall be allowed to flow from P3 to P2 (and not between other pins, but again leakage current is OK).
3. U1 shall not require its own power supply, i.e. it shall also work when the power supply is OFF.

*Without* requirement 3 I *could* use an inverter before the base of an NPN transistor to connect P2 and P3.

What element(s) can I use as U1 for achieving the named three requirements?

(Last time I submitted the question the text went away and only the circuit remained. Replaced the circuit by an image and try to submit again. And the I forgot D1 in the circuit, thanks to [ariser](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/54969/ariser) for pointing this out!)

[image: circuit]

Comment: Without constraint 1 and a diode, you could use a relay. (A diode is needed to prevent the capacitor from acting as the power source, currently it's parallel and can't be distinguished from the voltage source)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGjkAZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Power gone = current through resistor now functions to drive Q2, which current is miniscule compared to LED current. Done. No need to fuss about "nA". Even thinking about μA is absolutely pointless, since your LED will need 1mA at the least to be somewhat meaningful as an attention getting indicator.

Comment: One could use FETs instead of BJT. There's some room for reducing the standby current.

Comment: @Ariser You can, but then you're still talking about a 50uA reduction compared to the 5mA the LED drains (or the 30mA with the resistor chosen by OP), which I deemed not worth talking about the difference between a MOSFET and BJT, on account of if I were building it I wouldn't even care which one of the two I was holding at first blind grab.